# User Built-in Camera of Device

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, vue.js

i am currently working on a VueJs Project. My goal is to force user to use built-in camera of the device.
For example, if a user is using Virtual Camera ( ManyCam, OBS etc ), then i want to force him to use the Built-in Camera of the device issuing user a warning.

P.S: I know it is not possible to detect Virtual Camera on Browser. Is there any other way to go around it? Maybe in Python or any other server side scripts? Thank you for the help

I tried using Built-in functions of javascript

```
const devices = await navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices();
const videoDevices = devices.filter((device) => device.kind === "videoinput");
```

And then hardcoded the values on known Virtual cams as a keyword, but since its not a fool proof solution, i am thinking to go a step ahead.